# Show previous roll (Javascript lottery)

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a lottery game in Javascript where I generate 6 random unique numbers. These numbers get displayed in my first list. The problem is that we need to make a 'previous roll' feature. How do you make sure from the 2nd roll, you can see the previous roll?

Thanks in advance

```js
function generatenumbers() {
  let number = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 6) {
    let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
    if (number.includes(val) === false) {
      number.push(val);
      i++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = "";
  i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= number.length - 1; i++) {
    let node = document.createElement("LI");
    let txt = document.createTextNode(number[i]);
    node.appendChild(txt);
    document.getElementById("generated").appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="cf">
  <header>
    <h1>Hipster Powered Lottery</h1>

  </header>

  <section>
    <h2>Play with our wonderful lottery est. 1831</h2>
    <a href="#" id="generate" onclick="generatenumbers()">Generate my numbers!</a>
    <ul id="generated"></ul>

  </section>
  <aside>
    <h2>Previously generated set</h2>
    <ul id="previous"></ul>

  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the child elements of `#generate` to `#previous` before you generate the new numbers. Here is an example:

```js
function generatenumbers() {
  document.getElementById("previous").innerHTML = "";
  Array.from(document.getElementById("generated").children).forEach(child => {
    document.getElementById("previous").append(child);
  });
  let number = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 6) {
    let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
    if (number.includes(val) === false) {
      number.push(val);
      i++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = "";
  i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= number.length - 1; i++) {
    let node = document.createElement("LI");
    let txt = document.createTextNode(number[i]);
    node.appendChild(txt);
    document.getElementById("generated").appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="cf">
  <header>
    <h1>Hipster Powered Lottery</h1>

  </header>

  <section>
    <h2>Play with our wonderful lottery est. 1831</h2>
    <a href="#" id="generate" onclick="generatenumbers()">Generate my numbers!</a>
    <ul id="generated"></ul>

  </section>
  <aside>
    <h2>Previously generated set</h2>
    <ul id="previous"></ul>

  </aside>
</div>
```

I've followed your style of coding so that you'll understand what is going on but you should simplify this by creating variables to reference the elements instead of always accessing them using `document.getElementById(..)`

Here is a simplified version:

```js
const previous = document.getElementById("previous");
const generated = document.getElementById("generated");

function generatenumbers() {
  previous.innerHTML = "";
  previous.append(...generated.children);
  let number = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 6) {
    let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
    if (!number.includes(val)) {
      number.push(val);
      i++;
    }
  }
  generated.innerHTML = "";
  i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= number.length - 1; i++) {
    let node = document.createElement("LI");
    let txt = document.createTextNode(number[i]);
    node.appendChild(txt);
    generated.appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="cf">
  <header>
    <h1>Hipster Powered Lottery</h1>

  </header>

  <section>
    <h2>Play with our wonderful lottery est. 1831</h2>
    <a href="#" id="generate" onclick="generatenumbers()">Generate my numbers!</a>
    <ul id="generated"></ul>

  </section>
  <aside>
    <h2>Previously generated set</h2>
    <ul id="previous"></ul>

  </aside>
</div>
```